# Is there a faster way to switch between program instances?

Tags: usability

I find it kinda slow to have to wait for the animation when all the instances of a program (e.g. all open firefox windows) are placed as thumbnails over the screen. Is there a faster/smoother way to switch between instances of a program without having to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> through ALL programs? Or an easy way to speed up or prevent the animation?

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: `Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
` Perfectly works with `alt`+`\``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you keep pressed <kbd>Super</kbd>, it shows <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to switch to another window of the same application, but I have an italian keyboard so I don't know if it works for other configs.

Probably, in your keyboard layout you should use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key-above-tab</kbd>

Comment: That "key above tabe" was the hint I needed :D thanks very much

Comment: "key-above-tab", I found that hilarious. It's called `tick`(lowercase) or `tilde`(uppercase)

Comment: @shriek: if your read carefully, I intend whatever key is in that position, depending on the country of the keyboard.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the menu opened even when stop pressing alt ?

Answer (score 16):

Try using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. This can be used with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between instances of other open programs.

Comment: sounds nice, but unfortunately I have a german keyboard layout. there the backtick is only accessible via pressing the shift key and the forward tick key at the same time. in short: the shortcut doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can position the mouse cursor over the launcher icon and turn the scroll-wheel to rapidly flick through instances of the application.  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the "backtick" key) does the same thing, but displays thumbnails of the app instances while you're switching.

Comment: that sounds like something I am looking, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. do I need to configure something for this?

Comment: It's a new feature in Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring).  I guess you're using an earlier version?

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry I can't upvote, because of not enough reputation:( Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

A note for KDE users: the default shortcut for this feature is <kbd>Alt+`</kbd>, which, by the way, is not very practical for some keyboard layouts (german, italian for example).

To change this to <kbd>Alt+\</kbd> (as it is the default in Unity) go to:

- System settings
- Keyboard shorcuts
- Global keyboard shortcuts
- Among KDE components Select "KWin"
- Search for the character <kbd>`</kbd>. It should appear the "Switch between  window application" shortcut.
- Change the default shortcut with your preferred key combination (I used <kbd>Alt+\</kbd>)